# PostgreSQL Order by first 3 letter of field string

Tags: postgresql

I have a column table like this in my table PostgreSQL database

```
| Product|
|--------|
|  A10A  |
|  A13   |
|  A12B  |
```

and i want to order it by the first like this:

```
| Product|
|--------|
|  A10A  |
|  A12B  |
|  A13   |
```

If i use the normal order by im not getting the exact same result that i want

Comment: `order by left(product, 3)`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i got this: ` function left(character varying, integer) does not exist`

Comment: Then you are using an outdated (and unsupported) Postgres version. You need to use `substr()` instead